# IBM XSeries 335 Timeout?

Tags: ibm

I have an IBM XSeries 335 1U Server. It was given to me. It uses a special cable for display, mouse and keyboard.

I boot the OS, everything is fine for a while and then at some point the display goes blank and I cannot do anything with with the keyboard and mouse and the display does not come back.

The machine is working, I can see hard drive activity, The display light is 'green' (not orange like typical display sleep). Pressing a key on the keyboard does nothing, neither does the mouse.

How can I get my display back so I can see what is going on?

Answer (score 4):

The reason for the special cables is so that you can daisy-chain a load of servers together and only need one monitor and keyboard etc - a built in KVM as it were.

There should be a button on the front somewhere, which is used to select that server to be the one used by the display and input. Next to it should be an indicator LED with the general 'monitor' symbol, and this should be green. Try pressing this button if you are having problems, although I never had to use it when only connected to a single server - I've never seen this problem myself